# VBA Code to update a field in access

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, vba

My goal is to update the specialty code field based on the entry in the specialty field. As an example, if they select `Nurse Practitioner`, I want the specialty code field to automatically update to `000`.

I've used the following code but to no avail:

```
Private Sub SpecialtyCode_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Me.SpecialtyCode.Value = DLookup("[HSD_Code]", "Crosswalk_ProviderHSD", 
"[Specialty] = Me.Specialty.Value")
End Sub
```

HSD Code is the specialty code I want to pull and the crosswalk is the table I want to reference.

I'd like to do the same for county and region data given a ZIP Code. I know my code is wrong. What's the proper syntax? Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Since you've tagged 'Forms', I assume your data is presented/selected on a form? Is your form 'bound' to an underlying recordset? Where are the 'selecting'? Is it a ComboBox?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn - Yes the form is bound to an underlying table which contains other data relevant to the provider. Yes it is a combo box of a list of specialties. These specialties and their correlating codes are located in a separate table entitled Crosswalk_ProviderHSD. I want the code field to update once the specialty is selected from the drop down.

Comment: Typically you use a combobox that has multiple columns - some of which you may choose to hide. Then you 'bind' the control to a certain column of the combobox so that when you select 'Nurse...', the actual database value is saved as '000'. i.e. the rowsource of the combobox selects whatever fields you want from the 'Crosswalk...' table (Nurse P...), including it's unique key (000). Set the ControlSource to the HSD Code in your bound table; set olumn width to 0 to hide certain columns; set Bound Column to the 'Nurse..' column.  Immediate save or save when moving to another record?

Comment: You might be overthinking it a bit... all of this should be possible with queries. Can you list all of your controls, and table names with pertinent fields? If your changing the underlying data, of a bound control, AfterUpdate with a Requery, may be more appropriate.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I tried your example but I can't find the ControlSource option

Comment: I was referring to using a ComboBox, thus there is a property like: Me.cboSomeName.ControlSource

Comment: Under the lookup function for the field right? Not on the form? If so then yeah I understand that. I didn't know that VBA was involved though. That leads me to believe that you were talking about the form. In that case, let me try it all again.

Comment: @tahwos - My specialty code tables are named differently on the FE than they are the BE, so I'll list both names. *Crosswalk_ProviderHSD* is the BE table with fields *Specialty* and *HSD_Code*. The FE table has the same field names, but is titled *ProviderSpecialtyCodes*. The field names on the form are *Specialty* and *SpecialtyCode* respectively.

Comment: @Steven, So you have two different tables, or 1 table with two different names? Because Access only cares, about the table names, as you see them in the Front End. If it is a linked table, and you renamed it, in the front end, then you need to use that name, when referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update the field in its own *BeforeUpdate* event. And your DLookup syntax is wrong.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.SpecialtyCode.Value = _
    DLookup("[HSD_Code]", "Crosswalk_ProviderHSD", "[Specialty] = '" & Me.Specialty.Value & "'")
End Sub
```

That said, listen to the comments regarding queries.